# Swagger UI showing HTTP HEAD method which is not supported by the API

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, aiohttp

I have developed an API Gateway using python's aiohttp module.

Now, I am trying to develop a swagger UI for the same server. 
For now, I am doing it by specifying commends in the function. 
Below is an example -

```
async def list_models(request):
    """
    List models API.
    ---
    tags:
    - models
    summary: List models
    description: This API lists models created till date.
    produces:
    - application/json
    responses:
    "200":
      description: List of all the models created.
    """
    url = MODELPERSISTENCE_SERVICE_URL + '/models/'
    return await execute_get_request(url)
```

However when I deploy the server and visit the swagger UI I see that HTTP HEAD method is also supported by this API which is wrong.

As you can see I am not mentioning HEAD or GET method anywhere in the specification. How do I prevent HEAD method from popping up in the swagger UI?

Here is the image to show the HEAD method in play - 
[image: get and head method in place of just head method]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use `add_get` to add routes? Then Swagger is not wrong.

[aiohttp creates HTTP HEAD handlers by default](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#handler) when using the `router`'s `add_get` method. If you don't want them, register the routes with the [`allow_head=False` named parameter](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.UrlDispatcher.add_get).